# SWT FileDialog extended

Tags: java, swt

I am creating a SWT based application. I have a button named "Import" and on click this open up a swt FileDialog to select a file. I have a unique requirement when this FileDialog opened I wanted to show all files from specific folder only [means not entire filesystem, user cant go back,].Thanks in advance, Tor

Answer (score 2):

`FileDialog` has a method, `setFilterPath`, that allows you to specify the initial directory for the dialog.

You're going to have to modify `FileDialog` so that the user can't go back higher than the initial directory.  Here's the [source code](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.java.html) for `FileDialog` on Eclipse 3.5.